# Setup scripts fail integration tests in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, phpunit, integration-test

I have [setup integration tests for app/code](https://www.integer-net.com/integration-tests-with-magento-2/) that was working fine.

Now I have a module that adds some product attributes in a setup script, it doesn't have any tests but it is part of the project. When running integration tests it will fail with the exception: **Wrong entity ID**

This happens when the setup does this:
`$eavSetup->addAttribute(Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeDefinition);`

The error happens because table **eav_entity_type** is empty for some reason. what am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `<const name="TESTS_CLEANUP" value="enabled"/>` in your `phpunit.xml` (which is the default), Magento starts the test suite with an empty database and runs **all** setup scripts.

In your case, it looks like the setup script of the custom module runs **before** the one of `Magento_Catalog` which adds the product type to `eav_entity_type`.

To overcome this, add `Magento_Catalog` as a [module dependency](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_depend.html).